# How to logout Apple ID in App Store since MacOS Mojave new look

Tags: mac-appstore, mojave

Since the redesign of the App Store in MacOS Mojave, I can't find the correct place to log out current Apple ID account or switch it.

Can anyone tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the Mac App Store Menu bar, go to Store → Sign Out to sign out.

[image]

The entry would change to Sign In after successful logout. You can also sign in by clicking on the Sign In button shown towards the bottom left of the Mac App Store window.

[image]

Comment: no, it doesn't work. On Sign In this piece of crap doesn't let pick username.

Comment: The "Sign Out" menu item does not seem to exist on current versions of the App Store (macOS 14.3). At its place is "Account", which brings me to an account area with no sign-out button in sight.

Comment: @DenisWashington The "Sign Out" option is the last item under Store menu.

Comment: @DenisWashington I am running into the same issue; no 'sign out' option under the store menu. is your account administered by someone else? mine is (work device).